# В чем разница между React-router BrowserRouter и HashRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Подскажите, в чем разница между BrowserRouter и HashRouter? И в каких случаях лучше использовать тот или этот вариант?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Краткий ответ:

Оба из них создадут специальный объект истории. Вы должны использовать `BrowserRouter`, если у вас есть сервер, который отвечает на запросы, и `HashRouter`, если вы используете статический файловый сервер типо **GithubPages**

#### Развернутый ответ:

**BrowserRouter**

Использует [API истории браузера](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API) (`popstate` , `replaceState` а также методы `pushState`) также не поддерживает старые браузеры (IE 9 и ниже)

```
<BrowserRouter
  basename={optionalString} 
  forceRefresh={optionalBool}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  keyLength={optionalNumber}
>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

`basename` - Базовый путь для всех локаций.

Пример:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/technologies">
    <Link to="/js"/> // рендерит <a href="/technologies/js">
    <Link to="/python"/> // рендерит  <a href="/technologies/python">
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

`getUserConfirmation` - Функция используетсья для подтверждения навигации.Вы можете использовать эту опцию когда у вас есть `<MemoryRouter>` непосредственно с `<Prompt>`.

Грубо говоря когда не надо дать пользователю перейти со страницы (например форму начал заполнять и бросил)

---

`forceRefresh` - Если значение будет `true` `router` будет полностью обновлять страницы каждый раз когда вы переходите по ним.

---

`keyLength` - Определяет какой длины должен быть свойство `location.key` значение по умолчанию 6.(Максимум 11 символов хотя это не написано в документации)

**HashRouter**

использует  `hash` в `URL` ( `window.location.hash` ) для манипуляции роутами

```
<HashRouter
  basename={optionalString}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  hashType={optionalString}
>
  <App />
</HashRouter>
```

`hashType` - Тип кодирования для использования в `window.location.hash`.Доступные значение `slash` , `noslash` и `hashbang`.

- `slash` - Создает хеш типо `#/` также `#/main/profile`
- `noslash` - Создает хеш типо `#` также `#main/profile`
- `hashbang` - Третий вариант устарел и не поддерживаетсья Google-ом не использую и не советую

*Ответ был обновлён но оставлю свой старый ответ также тут (ниже) может кому понадобится.*

**Все очень просто.**

Для браузерных проектов есть `BrowserRouter` и `HashRouter` компоненты. `BrowserRouter` — следует использовать когда вы обрабатываете на сервере динамические запросы, а `HashRouter` используйте когда у вас статический веб сайт.

**Приведу пример:**

Если вы какой нибудь React проект зальете в github используя `BrowserRouter` и `gh-pages` он не будет работать.Точнее роуты не будут работать.

**Почему?**

Да потому что это статический проект и тут надо использовать `HashRouter` пример проекта вот  [**тут**](https://github.com/DuudeXX8/Storage/blob/master/src/App.js) можете посмотреть .Как видно из кода я там использую `HashRouter`

Если ваш проект предполагает использование backend-а то используйте `BrowserRouter`

Comment: А как BrowserRouter связан с бэком? Я сейчас начинаю писать проект, в котором будет бэк, но пока ещё бэк не сделал вообще... Прикрутил BrowserRouter - все вроде работает как нужно.

Comment: @Александр если используешь `create-react-app` то он без проблем работает пока не заливаешь на сервак.`create-react-app` по умолчанию используют как сервер ноду поэтому.

Comment: во вторых как связан в бэком:`BrowserRouter ` работает с веб сервером который в свою очередь должен быть настроен под одностраничные приложения.