# React defaul path doesn;t work after deploy to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

[image: Реакт приложение , на localhost работает нормально а после деплоя на githyb pages при загрузке не грузит компонент по дефолтному пути '/']

Реакт приложение , на localhost работает нормально а после деплоя на githyb pages при загрузке не грузит компонент по дефолтному пути '/'

Comment: hashrouter или browserrouter?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997296/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-react-router-browserrouter-%d0%b8-hashrouter/997300#997300