# React - пустой сайт на gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

При публикации реакт-приложения на gh-pages отображается просто пустая страница.
Репозиторий: https://github.com/IvanZemsky/r-router-1
Главная ветка - master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените вот [**здесь**](https://github.com/IvanZemsky/r-router-1/blob/master/src/index.js)

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

на

```
import {HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

и все будет работать. Развернутый ответ [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997296/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-react-router-browserrouter-%D0%B8-hashrouter/997300#997300)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Но у меня ещё есть другой репозиторий https://github.com/IvanZemsky/react-users-list-1, в котором тоже не работает, хотя там нет роутера вообще.

Comment: @IvanZemsky вы правы, вот это я пропустил. У вас имя репозитория должно заканчиваться на `github.io`. Тут документация -> https://docs.github.com/ru/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло.

Comment: @IvanZemsky в таком случае примите ответ нажав на галочку рядом с ответом. Удачи